# Logging the delay based on the events

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, timer, stopwatch

I have interfacing application where i need to calculate the time elapsed for various operations.

```
   public void Startoperation1()  
    {  
      Stopwatch stopWatch1 = new Stopwatch();
      stopWatch.Start();  
    }  

    public void StopOperation1()  
    {  
     stopWatch1.Stop(); 


     if(stopWatch1.TimeElapsed > tsActualTimeNeededForOperation1)
     {
     MessageBox.Show("Delay Occured in operation 1:"+ (stopWatch1.TimeElapsed - tsActualTimeNeededForOperation1).ToString());
    //Log to database about the delay
     }

    }
```

Start and stop operations are raised by separate class.
Like this there are 25 operations. I have to use 25 stopwatches and for all operations i have to write 50 methods to log the delays.
Any idea to reduce the use code and no of stopwatches(like using the timestamp of the system) i.e a generic method??

Comment: If your code is synchronous then you don't need a whole lot of Stopwatch instances. You can read the Elapsed property anytime while the Stopwatch is running... i.e, you don't need to call Stop() every time you need the time measure. This only makes sense when your calls are completed in a synchronized manner.

Comment: Never over-estimate the value of a "It took longer than expected" message when the user doesn't stand a chance to figure out **why** it took longer.  Use a profiler to measure the base line, write your system requirements to ensure that this result is reproducible after you ship your code.

Comment: So you write 25*50 methods to log your information? Are they 50 methods identically foreach operation?

Comment: @CodeWeed but all the operations will not start at same time.

Comment: @Olivarsham You start the Stopwatch and notice delay after the any operation using Elapsed property. (save this value in a variable) When you check delay for the next operation, you can use the delta of current Elapsed value and the previous Elapsed value(Depends on how you want the operation delays, delta or cumulative). It would be easier for you to have a static Stopwatch object in a class and access it from different classes in your application, every time you need to check the operation delays. Then you dont have to calculated the delta every time. Instead use the Start() Stop() methods.

Answer (score 1):

you can create multiple object at one time....and then  use for loop.....
like ..  to execute them one by one....

```
stopwatch stopwatch1[]=new stopwatch[50];
for
{
//...

}
```